# Can i run a Python file just like I'm typing the content in interactive mode?

Tags: python

For example I have a `test.py`:

```py
s='123'
print(s)
```

I'd like this output, just like I manually type them in `python`:

```py
>>> s='123'
>>> print(s)
123
```

But I want to run the **file** from CLI. `python test.py` and `python -i test.py` are not showing like that, so are `ipython test.py` and `ipython -i test.py`.

Comment: `python test.py` will work if you're correct re: how you have things set up. What happens when you run that?

Comment: I want to see the statements. It's like a Windows' batch file. `python test.py` will only show `123`, not show `>>>...`.

Comment: @imba-tjd I don't know of a way to have it run and show the lines being run. That would be only useful for the tiniest of programs. Any normal size program would spend the entire execution spamming the lines it's running, so fast you wouldn't be able to read them. It wouldn't be practical.

Comment: as I know Python doesn't have function to show line which it runs. You would have to write own interpreter for Python. If you want to see which line is execute then maybe you should learn how to use debuger.

Comment: for small program you could run it on [PythonTutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/) and it will show which line it runs and show what values you have in all variables.

Comment: The `trace` module is close to what you are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html

Comment: If this is for teaching purposes you could use Jupyter Notebook. Or maybe you are looking for something like `trace` or `coverage.py` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/trace.html https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/

Answer (score 1):

Save the following in a file called `tracer.py`:

```
import sys

class Tracer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._filecache = {'<string>' : open(sys.argv[1], 'r').readlines() or '\n'}
        self._linecache = {'<string>' : 0}

    def accept(self, fn):
        if fn != "<string>": # from exec
            return False
        return True

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        fn = frame.f_code.co_filename
        if not self.accept(fn):
            return self.trace

        if fn not in self._filecache:
          # wait until importing of the module is done to minimize pollution
            f = frame.f_back
            while f is not None:
                try:
                    if 'import' in _filecache[f.f_code.co_filename][f.f_lineno]:
                        return self.trace
                except Exception:
                     pass
                f = f.f_back
            del f

          # import is done, and we're back, accept this file from this point on
            self._filecache[fn] = open(fn, 'r').readlines() or '\n'
            self._linecache[fn] = sys.maxsize

        lno = frame.f_lineno

        ncur = self._linecache[fn]
        buf = self._filecache[fn]

        if event == 'line':
            for i in range(ncur, lno):
                ncur = self._oneline(i, buf)

            self._linecache[fn] = max(ncur, lno)

        elif event == 'return':
            if lno <= ncur:
                fln = frame.f_code.co_firstlineno - 1
                self._oneline(fln, None)
        return self.trace

    def _oneline(self, lineno, buf):
        print('>>> ', end='')

      # simple eol case
        if not buf or not buf[lineno]:
            print()
            return

      # in general, an interpreter "line" may be longer than a file line
        line = buf[lineno].rstrip()
        haseol = False
        while line and (line[-1] in ('(', '\\', ':') or line[0] in (' ', '\t')):
         # this line appears to have a continuation ...
            try:
             # output traced line
                print(line)

             # output continued line
                lineno += 1
                print('... ', end='')
                line = buf[lineno].rstrip()
            except IndexError:
             # shouldn't happen; but must mean that the diagnosis above is
             # wrong and that there is no continuation, keep silent
                break
        else:
            print(line)
            haseol = True

        if not haseol:
            print()

        return lineno

sys.settrace(Tracer().trace)
exec(open(sys.argv[1]).read())
sys.settrace(sys._getframe(0).f_trace)
```

store the code you want to trace in its own file. E.g. your sample code, say `test.py`:

```
s = '123'
print(s)
```

and run it as follows:

```
$ python3 tracer.py test.py
```

which produces the desired:

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> print(s)
123
>>>
```

I haven't tested it in anger, so there may be corner cases. Nevertheless, this should get you underway.